# path to connect controller.js in Asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio

i learns a AngularJS use examples, i followed one example - 
i have the next files:

*hola.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > <head>
    <title>My APP</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/controller.js"></script>
     </head> <body ng-app="angularjs">
    <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
        {{ greeting }}
    </div> </body> </html>
```

and *controller.js*:

```
var myApp = angular.module('angularjs', [])
myApp.controller('GreetingController', [function ($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

for connect controller.js file i tried  use:

```
<script src="Controllers/controller.js"></script>
```

and

```
 <script src="~/Controllers/controller.js"></script>
```

[image]
but nothing didn't happened,
what "Connection path" to my *controller.js* i slould use ?

Comment: What error did you see on browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks gyus for your answers. 
1)i was in View folder, and my path to controller looks like as:

```
Views/Controllers/controller.js
```

i moved my *controller.js* to View folder - i't OK.

2) i changed my code from my *controller.js* to:

```
var myApp = angular.module('angularjs', []);
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

Comment: don't put your *.js file under view directory. its not a good practice

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semi-colon at the end of this line:

```
var myApp = angular.module('angularjs', []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, Inline array annotation may cause the problem,

```
var myApp = angular.module('angularjs', []);    
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```